# Turning based on joystick axis degree with Unity's new Input System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code:

```
void Update()
{
    if (playerControls.Player.Jump.triggered)
    {
        Jump();
    }

    if (playerControls.Player.TurnLeft.triggered)
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    Vector2 move = playerControls.Player.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>();

    Debug.Log(move);

    if (move.x < 0)
    {
        Debug.Log(move);
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * rotateSpeed * Mathf.Abs(move.x) * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else if (move.x > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log(move);
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotateSpeed * Mathf.Abs(move.x) * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

This *mostly* works, but I'm trying to repeat the rotate action while the button is held, and using IsPressed instead of triggered gives me the following error:

> Cannot convert method group 'IsPressed' to non-delegate type 'bool'.
> Did you intend to invoke this method?

I can solve this by creating a Boolean that changes on trigger/release, but I also want to use move.x to detect the controller's X axis to be able to turn slower based on how far the joystick is pushed to the left or right.

How can I repeat the action while a button is pressed down, and in the case of a controller being used, how can I get the x-axis value of the joystick to control the speed of rotation?

Answer (score 0):

`IsPressed()` is a method. You want to use `isPressed` property. Notice small 'i'.